# Python currency converter using functions with two functions

Tags: function, converters, currency

def main():

```
Print_menu()
currency_converter()
```

## 1) Print_menu function should be void with no argument

def Print_menu():

```
print('Please choose from the menu.')       
print('============================')       
print('1: Convert between USD and EUR')     
print('2: Convert between USD and Canada')  
print('3: Convert between USD and UK (GBP)')
print('4: Convert between USD and China')   
print('5: Quit')                            
print('============================')       
menu = int(input('Enter your Choice: '))
```

## 2) This currency_converter function needs two arguments, exchange rate and

## name of currency unit. This can be void that takes an exchange rate and unit

## to calculate and print result. I am very new at writing code, and can't figure our how to call these functions to create a working program. Thanks ahead for any input

def currency_converter():

```
while menu >=1 and menu <=4:
    if menu == 1:
         menu = int(input('Enter the amount in dollar: '))
         men1 = menu 
         men1 = menu * 91/100 
         print('\t','$', menu,'is', format(men1,'.2f'),'euro')
    elif menu == 2:
        menu = int(input('Enter the amount in dollar: '))
        men1 = menu 
        men1 = menu * 137/100 
        print('\t','$', menu, 'is', format(men1,'.2f'), 'cad')
    elif menu == 3:
        menu = int(input('Enter the amount in dollar: '))
        men1 = menu 
        men1 = menu * 72/100 
        print('\t','$', menu, 'is', format(men1,'.2f'), 'pound')
    elif menu == 4:
        menu = int(input('Enter the amount in dollar: '))
        men1 = menu 
        men1 = menu * 653/100 
        print('\t','$', menu, 'is', men1, 'yuan')

if menu == 5:
    print('Thank you for using my program.')

else:
    print(menu, 'is an invalid choice.')
```

## 3) once currency is selected I need a while loop to ask if want to convert to-

## another unit. I am currently still writing this part and feel fairly confident I can do it.

main()

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Be sure to format your question in a readable manner - especially for python where that matters a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would add a return statement to Print_menu to return the menu value and change def currency_converter(): to def currency_converter(menu): then call one inside the other inside a main function.

```
def main():
    currency_converter(Print_menu())

if __name__==__main__:main()
```